# failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=user_db user=gorm database=gorm`

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, go-gorm

## Envs

```
gorm.io/gorm v1.20.6
gorm.io/driver/postgres v1.0.
```

## Error Texts

```
user_1     | [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=user_db user=gorm database=gorm`: dial error (dial tcp 172.18.0.2:9920: connect: connection refused)
user_1     | panic: failed to connect to `host=user_db user=gorm database=gorm`: dial error (dial tcp 172.18.0.2:9920: connect: connection refused)
```

All logs

```
$ docker-compose up
Starting urlshortener_user_db_1 ... done
Starting urlshortener_user_1    ... done
Starting urlshortener_gateway_1 ... done
Attaching to urlshortener_user_db_1, urlshortener_user_1, urlshortener_gateway_1
user_db_1  | 
user_db_1  | PostgreSQL Database directory appears to contain a database; Skipping initialization
user_db_1  | 
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.059 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13.0 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 9.3.0) 9.3.0, 64-bit
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.059 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.059 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.070 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
gateway_1  | [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Creating an Engine instance with the Logger and Recovery middleware already attached.
gateway_1  | 
gateway_1  | [GIN-debug] [WARNING] Running in "debug" mode. Switch to "release" mode in production.
gateway_1  |  - using env:      export GIN_MODE=release
gateway_1  |  - using code:     gin.SetMode(gin.ReleaseMode)
gateway_1  | 
gateway_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /api/v1/users/login       --> github.com/Asuha-a/URLShortener/api/controllers.Login (3 handlers)
gateway_1  | [GIN-debug] POST   /api/v1/users/signup      --> github.com/Asuha-a/URLShortener/api/controllers.Signup (3 handlers)
gateway_1  | [GIN-debug] Environment variable PORT is undefined. Using port :8080 by default
gateway_1  | [GIN-debug] Listening and serving HTTP on :8080
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.082 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2020-11-13 04:17:25 UTC
user_1     | 
user_1     | 2020/11/13 04:21:54 /go/src/github.com/Asuha-a/URLShortener/api/services/user/db/user.go:15
user_1     | [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=user_db user=gorm database=gorm`: dial error (dial tcp 172.18.0.2:9920: connect: connection refused)
user_1     | panic: failed to connect to `host=user_db user=gorm database=gorm`: dial error (dial tcp 172.18.0.2:9920: connect: connection refused)
user_1     | 
user_1     | goroutine 1 [running]:
user_1     | github.com/Asuha-a/URLShortener/api/services/user/db.Init()
user_1     |    /go/src/github.com/Asuha-a/URLShortener/api/services/user/db/user.go:19 +0x1ed
user_1     | main.main()
user_1     |    /go/src/github.com/Asuha-a/URLShortener/api/services/user/main.go:34 +0x37
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.175 UTC [21] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.180 UTC [21] LOG:  redo starts at 0/15D6CE0
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.180 UTC [21] LOG:  invalid record length at 0/15D6D18: wanted 24, got 0
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.180 UTC [21] LOG:  redo done at 0/15D6CE0
urlshortener_user_1 exited with code 2
user_db_1  | 2020-11-13 04:21:54.208 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

## Code

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  gateway:
    build:
      context: ./api/
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    tty:
      true
    depends_on:
      - user
  user:
    build:
      context: ./api/services/user
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 50051:50051
    tty:
      true
    depends_on: 
      - user_db
  user_db:
    image: postgres:alpine
    environment: 
      POSTGRES_USER: gorm
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: gorm
      POSTGRES_DB: gorm
      POSTGRES_HOST: user_db
    ports:
      - 9920:9920
```

user.go(initializing database)

```golang
package db

import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var (
    db  *gorm.DB
    err error
)

// Init DB
func Init() {
    db, err = gorm.Open(postgres.New(postgres.Config{
        DSN: "host=user_db user=gorm password=gorm dbname=gorm port=9920 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Tokyo",
    }), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    autoMigration()
}

// Close DB
func Close() {
    dbSQL, err := db.DB()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    dbSQL.Close()
}

func autoMigration() {
    db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
}
```

## What I tried

When I add 'container_name: "user_db"' in the docker-compose.yml, I got the same error.

When I change the hostname to 'user_db:9920', it seems to not be recognized as a hostname.

```
user_1     | [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=user_db:9920 user=gorm database=gorm`: hostname resolving error (lookup user_db:9920: Try again)
user_1     | panic: failed to connect to `host=user_db:9920 user=gorm database=gorm`: hostname resolving error (lookup user_db:9920: Try again)
```

## What I want to know

I know that I have to set the container name as the hostname and I set the 'user_db' defined in docker-compose.yml.
Why can't I init DB?

Comment: this image `image: postgres:alpine` will be exposed port `9920` ?

Comment: try to change `- 9920:9920` to `- 5432:5432` and port `port=5432`

Comment: @ThanhNguyenVan You were right. 9920 seems to be not exposed. I tried 5432 and now it works! Thank you!

Comment: let me put it to an answer  and tick it as right answer ! thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the image `postgres:alpine` is being exposed port `5432`.

Try to change `- 9920:9920` to `- 5432:5432` and port in connection string to
`port=5432`

Comment: I was getting the same error, when I switched the address to `5432`, now I am getting this: `Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint dreamy_cerf (fb0ca878974d3f69eb10c9cba1624ac13a15f5dfe25043f2e5f141988825debf): Error starting userland proxy: listen tcp4 0.0.0.0:5432: bind: address already in use.
ERRO[0000] error waiting for container: context canceled `

As my postgres is running on local `5432`