# failed to initialize database, dial error (dial tcp 192.168.32.2:5432: connect: connection refused)

Tags: postgresql, docker, go, docker-compose, go-gorm

### GO, Gorm, Postgres, Docker

#### Error ->  [error] failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=amazon-shopping-backend-db-1 user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp 192.168.80.2:5432: connect: connection refused)

backend                       | panic: failed to connect to `host=amazon-shopping-backend-db-1 user=postgres database=postgres`: dial error (dial tcp 192.168.80.2:5432: connect: connection refused)

#### **config/db.go**

```
package config

import (
    "amazon-backend/models"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

var DB *gorm.DB

func Connect() {
    // dsn := "host=amazon-shopping-backend-db-1 user=postgres password=1234 dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai"
    dsn := "postgresql://postgres:1234@amazon-shopping-backend-db-1:5432/postgres?sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&models.Seller{}, &models.Cart{}, &models.Inventory{}, &models.EachCartItem{}, &models.Orders{}, &models.Product{}, &models.User{})
    DB = db
}
```

#### **dockercompose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./data/db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
  backend:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: backend
    ports:
      - "${BACKEND_PORT}:${BACKEND_PORT}"
    depends_on: 
      - db
    environment:
      - BACKEND_PORT=${BACKEND_PORT}
```

#### **Containers**

[Docker ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsito.png)

i referred to these : But none of them worked

[failed to initialize database, got error failed to connect to `host=user_db user=gorm database=gorm`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64815586/failed-to-initialize-database-got-error-failed-to-connect-to-host-user-db-user)

[connect: cannot assign requested address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59224272/connect-cannot-assign-requested-address)

https://github.com/quay/clair/issues/134#issuecomment-491300639

Comment: Don't you need some localhost/127.0.0.1 somewhere ? Or set a network between your containers ?

Comment: The Compose service name `db` should work as a host name here.  Compose already provides a network named `default` for you; also see [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation.  The other obvious potential cause is the application starting up before the database is ready, in which case [Docker Compose wait for container X before starting Y](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) might help.